# How can I count the number of rectangles with a minimal length?

Tags: python, eclipse, opencv

I have the code below that I use to find if there is any dicontinuity on railways. The idea is to create bounding box and if there are 2 boxes, it means that everything is okay. Otherwise, if I have more than 2 boxes, it means that there is a discontinuity. So, at the end of my code, I put a function `print len(contours)`.

The problem is that when I have my final image (with blue rectangles), we can see those I need (those that cover the railways), but also some really little rectangles I don't want. It means that the function `print len(contours)` send me back a message telling me that there are 19 rectangles for example.

My idea is to make a little function, asking the programme to count the number of rectangles with a minimal length or width (so it would count only the rectangles that cover the railways). I am a beginner in coding with Python and I have no idea about how to code this, does anyone can help me please?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Here is my code:

```
 import numpy as np
 import argparse
 import cv2


 image = cv2.imread('..\img.jpg')
 frame = cv2.resize(image,(500,500))

 """boundaries = [
     ([17, 15, 100], [50, 56, 200]),
     ([86, 31, 4], [220, 88, 50]),
     ([25, 146, 190], [62, 174, 250]),
     ([103, 86, 65], [145, 133, 128])]"""

 boundaries = [([100, 100, 100], [255, 255, 255])]

 for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
     # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
         lower = np.array(lower, dtype = "uint8")
         upper = np.array(upper, dtype = "uint8")

     # find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
     # the mask
         mask = cv2.inRange(frame, lower, upper)
         output = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = mask)


     # show the images
         cv2.namedWindow("images", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
         cv2.resizeWindow("images", 1000, 500)
         cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([frame, output]))
         cv2.waitKey(0)


 gray=cv2.cvtColor(output,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(gray,25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
 contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 for cnt in contours:
     x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
     cv2.rectangle(output,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)


 cv2.imshow('image2',output)
 cv2.waitKey(0)


 print len(contours)
```

Here are my results (left image is the original, middle image allows us to see only the railways and right image detects the railways with boundary boxes) :

[Results when there is not any discontinuity (the code says that there are 4 rectangles)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPwYe.png)

[Results when there is a discontinuity (the code says that there are 19 rectangles)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Iir.png)

Comment: Never worked with CV2, but I see a line `cv2.rectangle(output,(x,y),(x+w,y+h)`, so I assume, you could count those rectangles with w*h smaller than a threshold value and prevent their output in the picture.

Comment: @Piinthesky is correct. You can filter the contours by their area using `cv2.contourArea()`, or you can find their height and width using the bounding box and you can filter them by their aspect ratio. However note that `cv2.boundingRect` gives you upright rectangles, so if your rectangles are at an angle, you'll want the `cv2.minAreaRect()` which takes into account the rotation. See [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) for examples. Also note that the discontinuity isn't what is causing those spurious rectangles, but color filtering.

Answer (score 1):

In your result, we can see many `noisy regions`. So to get the counts of rectangles, you should do more `pre-post-processing` steps, such as `morph-op` on the binary, or removing the `noisy regions` by `area` or `width-height-ratio`.

In these two cases, doing `morph-op` is enough. But you can also do more processing on them.

---

croped images:

[image]

**situation 1**:

[image]

**situation 2**:
[image]

---

**Source code:**

```
## read and convert to gray 
img = cv2.imread("lines.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

## threshed 
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

## morph-op      
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
morphed = threshed.copy()
morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(morphed, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel, iterations=1)
morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(morphed, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations=2)

## find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
print(len(cnts))

## removingt noisy regions by area
cnts = list(filter(lambda cnt: cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 100, cnts))
print(len(cnts))
```

Comment: All right ! I'll try with this. Thank you for your help :)